# Не обновляются пакеты Ubuntu из-за ошибки grub-efi

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub, vds

Использую `VDS` с установленной `Ubuntu 20.04`. Не удаётся обновить пакеты `apt update` и `apt upgrade`. Получаю ошибку из-за `grub-efi`. Вот то, что выводит консоль:

```
Hit:1 http://mirror.timeweb.ru/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://mirror.timeweb.ru/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://mirror.timeweb.ru/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://mirror.timeweb.ru/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Hit:5 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:6 http://zabbix.repo.timeweb.ru/ubuntu focal InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up grub-efi-amd64-signed (1.142.6+2.04-1ubuntu26.4) ...
Unknown device "/dev/disk/by-id/*": No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
 installed grub-efi-amd64-signed package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for shim-signed:
 shim-signed depends on grub-efi-amd64-signed | grub-efi-arm64-signed; however:
  Package grub-efi-amd64-signed is not configured yet.
  Package grub-efi-arm64-signed is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package shim-signed (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-efi-amd64-signed
 shim-signed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up grub-efi-amd64-signed (1.142.6+2.04-1ubuntu26.4) ...
Unknown device "/dev/disk/by-id/*": No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
 installed grub-efi-amd64-signed package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for shim-signed:
 shim-signed depends on grub-efi-amd64-signed | grub-efi-arm64-signed; however:
  Package grub-efi-amd64-signed is not configured yet.
  Package grub-efi-arm64-signed is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package shim-signed (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-efi-amd64-signed
 shim-signed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Можно было бы переустановить ОС. Но потом нужно будет заново устанавливать и настраивать окружение. Пробовал удалить и заново установить, но консоль выдаёт туже самую ошибку.

Можно ли исправить ошибку? И в чём может быть причина возникновения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка у вас тут:

Setting up grub-efi-amd64-signed (1.142.6+2.04-1ubuntu26.4) ...

Unknown device "/dev/disk/by-id/*": No such file or directory

post-installation script, который вызывает другой скрипт(/usr/lib/grub/grub-multi-install ) у вас и не может найти эту директорию, и возвращает установщику ошибку.

Comment: То есть, мне достаточно создать директорию /usr/lib/grub/grub-multi-install и ошибка исчезнет?

Comment: Нет, вам нужно разобраться куда у вас делаcь директория /dev/disk/by-id/

И смотреть конфиг grub

/usr/lib/grub/grub-multi-install - это не директория, это скрипт который вызывается при установке пакета.

Comment: @ford1813 интересно: у меня на одной из виртуалок в этом каталоге только ata-QEMU_DVD-ROM_QM00004 -> ../../sr0, то есть возможны варианты, когда там и вообще ничего нет. Отсюда допвопросы (риторические): почему дебиан решил, что надо ставить EFI-шный загрузчик? Если это действительно так необходимо, почему возможно возникновение ситуации, когда в /dev/disk/by-id ничего нет (при этом в других подкаталогах /dev/disk что-то имеется)?

Comment: ну на первый вопрос я вам не отвечу.

А на второй:

Симлинк в /dev/disk/by-id создастся только при наличии serial number'а.
https://cgit.freedesktop.org/systemd/systemd/tree/rules/60-persistent-storage.rules#n25